# Coloring in shapes in Visual Basic.Net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, colors, fill, shapes

I have a set of shapes created in visual basic that need to be colored in:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnDraw_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDraw.Click
    Dim formSurface As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics 'creates surface

    Dim world As New Pen(Color.Black, 3)
    formSurface.DrawRectangle(world, 250, 50, 300, 300) 'world


    Dim roof As New Pen(Color.Black, 3)
    Dim roof1 As New Point(325, 200)
    Dim roof2 As New Point(475, 200)
    Dim roof3 As New Point(400, 100)
    Dim roof4 As New Point(400, 100)
    Dim curvePoints As Point() = {roof1, roof2, roof3, roof4}
    formSurface.DrawPolygon(roof, curvePoints) 'triangle roof

    Dim body As New Pen(Color.Black, 3)
    formSurface.DrawRectangle(body, 325, 200, 150, 150) 'square body

    Dim sun As New Pen(Color.Black, 3)
    formSurface.DrawEllipse(sun, 450, 75, 50, 50) 'sun

    Dim door As New Pen(Color.Black, 3)
    formSurface.DrawRectangle(door, 387, 300, 25, 50) 'door

End Sub
```

End Class

Everything works perfectly; the shapes are all generated where I want them to be. (I'm trying to draw a house) However, how do I color them in? Also, if I do, will the colors overlap (I want that to happen)?

Should I use some function like `image.fill`? I know that isn't right but I'm looking for something like that.

Thanks!

Comment: @Tim Williams hey what did you edit? just curious.

Comment: You had the tag "VBA" instead of "VB.net"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the formSurface.FillPolygon, FillRectangle, and FillEllipse commands.  You can still use the Draw commands to create an outline with a different color than the fill.

The "Fill" commands need Brushes instead of pens.  (Pens draw lines, brushes fill space.)  The easiest type of brush to use would be like "Brushes.AliceBlue".

Comment: so like instead of DrawPolygon?

Comment: You can use it instead of DrawPolygon.  Or, you could do FillPolygon with one color, and DrawPolygon with another, to create a border with a different color than the fill, and make sure to do the "Draw" after the "Fill".

Comment: Should I be using brushes then, instead of pens? Right now, it's saying that I need to use brushed but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: So as you can see in my code, I have `Dim body As New Pen` should that be `Dim body as New Brush`? I've tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: If you use the "Brushes.WhateverColorYouWant" syntax, you don't need to "dim" a brush.  Just do fromSurface.FillPolygon(Brushes.AliceBlue, etc.

Comment: Or, you could create a brush with Dim.  If I recall, there is a SolidBrush, and maybe a TextureBrush or something.

Comment: Also, any "new" pens or brushes should probably be "disposed" of later by calling the Dispose method on them.  (The garbage collector will eventually get them I think, but it could cause performance issues I think.)